# Is there a way to filter out I/B/P frames in an MPEG Video stream and access the macroblock information?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, mpeg, libavcodec

I am trying make a program for video analysis of MPEG streams in C or C++.

I was able to find out the frame types in a video file using

```
ffprobe -show_frames -pretty File.mpg | grep 'pict_type' > pict_type.txt
```

However based on the order of the frames, it seems that they are in "display" (IBBPBBP...) order not in "transmission" order (IPBBPBBPBB...) and it's not exactly ideal way of doing things as I can't assure the command didn't skip any frames or anything as it's outside of my program.

I have tried OpenCV, but it appears the information I require is too low-level for OpenCV and I believe the solution lies in ffmpeg or libavcodec but the documentation is a nightmare past the CLI. Although I am open to other solutions!

The information I require are:

- The type of each frame (I, B, or P)
- The total number of macroblocks inside a frame
- The number of intra-coded macroblocks inside a P frame
- The number of both forward and backward predicted macroblocks inside a B frame
- The number of just backward predicted macroblocks inside a B frame
- The number of just forward predircted macroblocks inside a B frame

I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Did you find any way?